# Listar datos de Mysql en Listbox Python

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter, listbox

Estoy trabajando en el sisguiente codigo para listar los datos de una de mis tablas en Mysql en un ListBox de Python, pero me esta tirando error, en la linea 11 el error es el siguiente:

connection.row_factory = mysql.Row
AttributeError: module 'mysql' has no attribute 'Row'

Este es el trozo de codigo que estoy usando:

```
import mysql.connector
from tkinter import *

connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='127.0.0.1',
                                     database='test',
                                     user='root',
                                     password='')

if connection.is_connected():
connection.row_factory = mysql.Row
cursor = connection.cursor()
listData = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM test.plants")
customers = cursor.fetchall()
for name in customers:
print('{0}'.format(name[0]))
plants = '{0}'.format(name[0])
itemsforlistbox = [plants]
customerSelect = Tk()
sizex = 600
sizey = 400
posx = 40
posy = 20
customerSelect.wm_geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (sizex, sizey, posx, posy))
def CurSelect(evt):
value = str((mylistbox.get(mylistbox.curselection())))
print(value)
mylistbox = Listbox(plantsSelect, width=60, height=10, font=('times', 13))
mylistbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', CurSelect)
mylistbox.place(x=32, y=90)
for items in itemsforlistbox:
mylistbox.insert(END, items)
mainloop()
```

Que es lo que tengo mal, de antemano agradezco la ayuda que se me pueda brindar.

Saludos

DS

Comment: Estaba mirando en internet, no parece haber evidencia de que exista un atributo mysql.Row en el modulo mysql. Sin embargo, sospechando que tu código antes trabajaba con otra base de datos, decidí hecharle una mirada a la documentación de sqlite3 (que era uno de los resultados de mis busquedas). Allí [si existe algo similar](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Row). Estoy en lo cierto con que este código antes trabajaba con sqlite3?

Comment: Despues de más busquedas y leer [una pregunta del sitio en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68639430/how-can-i-get-an-sqlite3-row-like-row-factory-using-mysql-connector-python) parece que esta es la alternativa más similar a sqlite3.Row: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursornamedtuple.html. Puedes ver una lista de las otras alternativas aquí: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-cursor-subclasses.html

Comment: Gracias lo he solucionado con tu ayuda cerrado.